# SerializationException "is not marked as serializable" when trying to serialize a Dictionary

Tags: c#, forms, serialization

```
Full error : System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Type 'TagLib.Id3v2.AttachmentFrame' in Assembly 'taglib-sharp, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db62eba44689b5b0' is not marked as serializable.'
```

I am trying to serialize a dictionary for a form application.I am making an mp3 player and i want to be able to create playlists.I read that the Dictionary is marked as [Serializable] (and implements ISerializable) so serializing should be possible so i thought that i could use it.However when i m trying to serialize one i get the error above.Am i missing something?Shouldnt it be possible for the dictionary to be serialized without getting an error?
My code:

```
static Dictionary<String, Tracks> playlistTracks = new Dictionary<string, Tracks>();
        public Playlist()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string[] filenames, filepaths;
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "All Supported Audio | *.mp3; *.wma | MP3s | *.mp3 | WMAs | *.wma";
            if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                filepaths = openFileDialog1.FileNames;
                filenames = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames;
                for(int i = 0; i< filenames.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!playlistTracks.ContainsKey(filenames[i]))
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(filenames[i]);
                        Tracks track = new Tracks();
                        track.songName = filenames[i];
                        track.path = filepaths[i];
                        track.readMetaData(filepaths[i]);
                        playlistTracks.Add(filenames[i], track);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != "")
            {
                if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    Tracks.serializePlaylist(textBox1.Text, playlistTracks);
                }
            }
            else { MessageBox.Show("Choose a playlist name!"); }
        }
    }
```

The Tracks class:

```
[Serializable]
    class Tracks
    {

        public string  songName { get; set; }
        public string path { get; set; }
        public string album = "Unknown";
        public TimeSpan duration;
        public string artistName = "Unknown";
        public string musicGenre = "Unknown";
        public uint publishedYear = 0;
        private string language = "Unknown";
        private int playingFrequency = 0;
        public string title = "Unknown";
        public IPicture[] pictures;
        public bool picExists = false;
        public void readMetaData(string songPath)
        {

            #region AssignMetaDataToTrack

            var tfile = TagLib.File.Create(songPath);

            this.publishedYear = tfile.Tag.Year;
            if (tfile.Tag.FirstAlbumArtist !=null)
            {
                this.artistName = tfile.Tag.FirstAlbumArtist;
            }
            this.duration = tfile.Properties.Duration;
            if (tfile.Tag.FirstGenre !=null) {
                this.musicGenre = tfile.Tag.FirstGenre; }
            if (tfile.Tag.Album != null)
            {
                this.album = tfile.Tag.Album;
            }
            if (tfile.Tag.Title != null)
            {
                this.title = tfile.Tag.Title;
            }
            #endregion
            //check an uparxei artwork
            if (tfile.Tag.Pictures.Length > 0)
            {
                this.pictures = tfile.Tag.Pictures;
                picExists = true;
            }
        }



        public static void serializePlaylist(string playlistName , Dictionary<string,Tracks> playlist)
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            Stream st = new FileStream(@"Playlists\" + playlistName + ".txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            bf.Serialize(st, playlist);
        }


    }
```

Thanks in advance for any answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all: you use somewhere type `TagLib.Id3v2.AttachmentFrame` which is not marked as serializable.  Perhaps within your `IPicture` type, perhaps elsewhere.

If you have control over the library, mark the type as serializable.  If not, you must implement your own custom serializaton.  Or avoid using this type.  Or, finally, you can decide not to serialize the field of the type that contains `TagLib.Id3v2.AttachmentFrame`.

Comment: oh you are right.Thank you i will mark your answer as correct.